# AdMob v4.4 BOTTOM LEFT gravity does NOT work

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services

**NOTE: Am using the new GooglePlayServices AdMob at version 4.4**

When "onCreate" is call I create the content view like so:

```
ContentView = new FrameLayout(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
addContentView(ContentView, params);
```

When I set my AdView gravity, I do it like so:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(320, 50, Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT);
adView.setLayoutParams(viewParams);
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: What are the symptoms? Why are you using a FrameLayout instead of a LinearLayout? Show all the code (ie adding the AdView to your contentView).

Comment: LinearLayout is a stack align system.  I don't want that. This will be overlaying GLES in a game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the adview's parameters as follows:

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = 
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                viewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                viewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);

adView.setLayoutParams(viewParams);
```

Comment: That works, but how to I align to BOTTOM CENTER now?

Comment: Never mind, found it. Its RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL. Thanks!